# Finding $f'(x), f(x)= \frac{4x^5+12x^3-40x}{4(x^2+5)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm lost, my textbook says the answer is $3x^2-2.$ At this point in the book, they haven't taught quotient rule, but i tried it with quotient rule and I couldn't get $3x^2-2$. The only method they've shown for differentiating fractions involved separating each term in the numerator into an individual fraction, but I'm not sure how to do that here. If anyone can see what the book's expecting students to do, I'd really appreciate if they'd show me.

Comment: Try polynomial long division?

Comment: Hint: $4x^5+12x^3-40x = 4x^3(x^2+5) - 8x(x^2 + 5)$.

Comment: Perhaps you know how to divide numerator (a polynomial) by another polynomial (denominator) to find **the quotient and remainder**, i.e. what it is **long division**, as suggested by @peterwhy ?

Comment: I just tried it with polynomial division and I got x^(3)-2x, which is the same as the result that i got using the factorisation @Paul gave and doing (4x^(3)-8x)/4. Thankyou for the asnwers, they were really helpful.  I'm still not sure how the book ended up with 3x^(2) -2.

Comment: @lizziew $3x^2 -2$ is the derivative of $x^3 -2x$

Comment: i literally made the stupidest mistake I could have made, thankyou for helping an idiot out lmao. im sorry you had to point that out

Comment: @lizziew take the logarithm from both sides and apply the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't been taught the formula for deriving quotients, then the best thing is to differentiate $$f(x) = \frac{4x^5}{4x^2+20} + \frac{12x^3}{4x^2+20}-\frac{40x}{4x^2+20}$$
If you know how to find the derivative of a polynomial and a term of the form $\frac{a}{x-b}$, then it is straight since the only thing you have to do is to divide polynomials. For example, divide $4x^5$ between $4x^2+20$, and you obtain a quotient, which is a polynomial (easy to differentiate) and a remainder of the form $r(x) = \frac{a}{x-b}$, whose derivative is $r'(x) = a \ln(x-b)$. I would be grateful if you upvoted if this was useful.

Comment: You missed an $x$ in your third term. Not super important though.

Comment: Thanks, now I have changed it

Comment: The derivative of $r(x) = \frac{a}{x-b}$ should be $r'(x) = -\frac{a}{(x-b)^2}$. But here the remainder might be like $\frac{ax+b}{4x^2+20}$.

Comment: thankyou for the edit @DanielC.

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{note that} \ \ \ 4x^5+12x^3-40x= 4x(x^4+3x^2-10) =4x(x^2+5)(x^2-2)$$
$$f(x)= \frac{4x^5+12x^3-40x}{4(x^2+5)}=\frac{4x(x^2+5)(x^2-2)}{4(x^2+5)} = x(x^2-2) =x^3-2x$$
$$f'(x) =3x^2-2$$